# Does onChange event handler rerender the component every time you update an input or textarea in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, textarea

I'm developing a React app and I want to store the content of a textarea using the event handler onChange. However, as far as I know, react rerenders a component every time its state is updated.

Does this mean that the component will be rerendered with every new character I add to the textarea content? If so, it would be extremely inefficient from a performance perspective. What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: that's exactly how it's supposed to be and it's not inefficient given the way that react works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, component would be rerendered everytime that props or state changed. This is the way that React works. Inefficient from a performance perspective ? From https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html :

> **Unlike browser DOM elements**, React elements are plain objects, and are **cheap** to create. React DOM takes care of updating the DOM to match the React elements.

Creating or updating DOM element is more expensive, but re-rendering a component or changeing the state or props of a component isn't meant to change the DOM element：

> **React Only Updates What’s Necessary**
>
> React DOM compares the element and its children to the previous one, and only applies the DOM updates necessary to bring the DOM to the desired state.

So, don't worry about the cost of updating state or props, most of the case are overkill to avoid state updating.